# Accessing to MySql DataBase through PHP in InfinityFree

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I've registered a domain and got hosting and a mysql database from InfinityFree.

I haven't been coding in PHP for a long time, but here I'm trying to simply check the connection to the database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$host='sql*number*.epizy.com'; //mysql host name
$user='epiz_*number*';  //mysql username   
$pass='password';   //mysql password
$db='epiz_*number*_*database-name*'; //mysql database

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if($con) {
echo "Connection successful";
}
else {
  echo "Connection error";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The output for the page is

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
> 'epiz_*number*'@'*host-ip*' (using password: YES) in
> /home/vol5_8/epizy.com/epiz_*number*/htdocs/php_test.php on line 13
> Connection error

I read the most common errors and my .htaccess file is empty, so what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check their knowledge base: https://forum.infinityfree.net/docs?category=20&topic=49338#access-denied-for-user-4

Comment: Thank you! For anyone reading the issue was the db_password is different from the user_password in infinityfree

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading the issue was the mysql database password is different from the password you use to log into infinityfree (let's call it user_password)

> It could also mean that your database password is incorrect. The
> database password is the same as your hosting account password (which
> is different from your client area password!). You can find your
> hosting account password by logging in to your client area, select the
> account, scroll down to Account Password and click Show.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).